# Show line of zoomed in series when no points within zoom range using boost

Tags: highcharts

OK so if you have the boost module enabled, zooming in can hide some of the series'.  If a series has no points within the zoom range, the line is hidden altogether.  I would like to still show the line even if the series has no points inside the zoom range.

It works the way I want it to without the boost module but I need boost enabled.

Any ideas how I can solve this?  On the Fiddle, zoom in to March-May and watch the 2015-2015 series line disappear.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5cvwhyx/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9962

To workaround, you can add more data points or disable boosting when the chart is zoomed:

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
            if (typeof e.min == 'undefined' && typeof e.max == 'undefined') {
                this.chart.update({
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            boostThreshold: 1
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                this.chart.update({
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            boostThreshold: 0
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    ...
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4z2u9tpj/

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I figured it was a bug.  I am a bit nervous to disable boost on zoom given my dataset size but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Hi Mike Lehmann, Additionally, to increase performance you can disable boosting only in some zoom level or only in a specific xAxis range: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o7z06yw5/